# Normalizing data to 100% but total values are less than 1.00

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to normalize values while retaining their relative frequency.  For example, the total counts for one variable is 219, comprised of the values 56, 89, 145.  To normalize these data I divided each value by the total then visualized the results as a bar chart, shown below. Why aren't the total values summing to 1.00?

```
p.perc <- ggplot(bNTI.perc, aes(fill=variable,x=pond,y=value/total)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
print (p.perc)
```

[image]

Thank you!
My data:

```
> dput(bNTI.perc)
structure(list(pond = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("RHM", "TS", "SS", "Lilly"), class = "factor"), 
    total = c(291, 740, 241, 42, 291, 740, 241, 42, 291, 740, 
    241, 42), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("sum(cor > 2)", "sum(cor < -2)", 
    "sum(cor > 2 | cor < -2)"), class = "factor"), value = c(56L, 
    213L, 49L, 0L, 89L, 156L, 70L, 19L, 145L, 369L, 119L, 19L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do this manually. Use `position = 'fill'`:

```r
ggplot(bNTI.perc, aes(pond, value, fill = variable)) + geom_col(position = 'fill')
```

[image]

But the answer to your actual question is that your `total` column is wrong. There are three values for `Lilly` (0, 19 and 19), which sums to 38, yet your `total` for the `Lilly` group is 42, not 38, so your `Lilly` bar was only adding up to 38/42 (0.9047619). Similarly, your `SS` values of `119 + 70 + 49` add up to 238, yet your `total` for `SS` is 241